# C# wrong encoding

Tags: c#

I ran in to some Problems when I try to do this:

```
public byte[] Login()
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WA\x01\x00\x00\x19\xf8\x05\x01\xa0\x8a\x84\xfc\x11iPhone-2.6.7-5222\x00\x08\xf8\x02\x96\xf8\x01\xf8\x01\x7e\x00\x07\xf8\x05\x0f\x5a\x2a\xbd\xa7");
    }
```

these bytes `\x8a\x84` get both encoded to `\xbf\xbf` what I do not want. I already tried with Default Encoding, UTF and Unicode, but they all do not provide what I need.

This is a socket client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but they all do not provide what I need

Well we've no idea what you actually *do* need.

If you're trying to get the byte values `0x8a` and `0x84` then I suggest you avoid using text to start with - it doesn't look like this is *really* all text data in the first place. It looks like there are probably *bits* of text within it, and you could use an encoding for those aspects, but otherwise when you want fixed *binary* data, you should specify that as bytes, rather than decoding "text" which isn't really text.

It's *possible* that using `Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)` (ISO-8859-1) you'll get what you were *expecting*, but it's still not what you *should* be doing.

Comment: `"WA\x01\x00\x00\x19\xf8\x05\x01\xa0\x8a\x84\xfc\x11iPhone-2.6.7-5222\x00\x08\xf8\x02\x96\xf8\x01\xf8\x01\x7e\x00\x07\xf8\x05\x0f\x5a\x2a\xbd\xa7"` should be exactly the same, but as byte.

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes hit it. Thanks!

Comment: @Moritz: But that's *not the right way of doing it*, as I said before. Fundamentally you're *not* trying to represent Unicode U+008A for example (control character "line tabulation set") - you're trying to represent the *byte* 0x8a. So don't put it into text to start with.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII is not defined above value 127.

I would wonder why you are using a string intermediary to convert bytes to bytes.

You could, instead, do something like this and eliminate this problem altogether.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WA")
.Concat(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })
.Concat(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("iPhone-2.6.7-5222"))
.Concat(new byte[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 })
.ToArray()
```

Comment: "I already tried with Default Encoding, UTF and Unicode, but they all do not provide what I need."